# Won't be able to save output into csv format due to NameError

Tags: python, python-requests, export-to-csv, yelp

I won't able to save the output into csv format due to "NameError" occurred while running the code.
Here is the code:

```
import requests
import csv
import json

file = open("sample.csv", 'w', encoding='utf-8')     
writer = csv.writer(file, lineterminator='\n')
writer.writerow(["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday"])

api_key = 'XzQ7rb.....'
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer %s' % api_key}
search_api_url = 'https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/r0JxdG5StcD8eiHF9u01ZQ'

response = requests.get(search_api_url, headers=headers)
parsed = json.loads(response.text)
time = parsed.get('hours')
businesses = parsed["hours"]
for op in time:
    ab = op["open"]
    for div in ab:
        if div['day']==1:
           day_1 = div['start'][0:2] + ":" + div['start'][2:4] + " to " + div['end'][0:2] + ":" + div['end'][2:4]
        elif div['day']==2:
            day_2 = div['start'][0:2] + ":" + div['start'][2:4] + " to " + div['end'][0:2] + ":" + div['end'][2:4]
        elif div['day']==3:
            day_3 = div['start'][0:2] + ":" + div['start'][2:4] + " to " + div['end'][0:2] + ":" + div['end'][2:4]
            
            writer.writerow([day_1, day_2, day_3])     #NameError: name 'day_2' is not defined
        
file.close()
```

Comment: Your `if`...`elif`...`elif` will only ever set one of `day_1`, `day_2`, or `day_3`. What are you expecting the values to be of the two variables that you aren't setting?

Comment: i want all the values of day_1, day_2 and day_3 so what should i do?

Comment: Do you mean for `writer.writerow` to be outside of the loop? It's inside of the loop right now based on the indentation.

Comment: i tried 'writer.writerow' outside the loop but nothing happened.